# Line break in FastApi schema extra

Tags: swagger, fastapi

I am trying to add an example for an endpoint in FastAPI (according to https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/it/tutorial/schema-extra-example/) and one of the fields needs a multiline comment but however I try I am not able to do it. What should I add to get it to multiple lines.

I have tried:

- Multiline python string (\n)
- `<br>`
- `<br />`
- \ at the end of the line
- two spaces at the end of the line

nothing has worked, the Swagger UI displays the raw string no matter what I do.